# comparison of date >= but not including self

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, model-view-controller, methods

**model**

```
def previous_user_challenge_date_started
  user.challenges.where('date_started >= ?', date_started).order('date_started ASC').first #date_started is a date, not datetime
end
```

Some challenges will have the same `date_started` so that's why I want  `>=`, but right now it keeps reloading the current `@challenge` over and over again when the `link_to` is clicked.

How can I use `>=` but with an exception for whatever is the `@challenge`, so maybe using `not self` somehow in the model method?

**view**

```
<%= link_to '← Previous', challenge_path(@challenge.previous_user_challenge_date_started), class: "prev" %>
```

**controller**

```
@challenge = Challenge.find(params[:id])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scopes are really handy for this kind of thing:

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  # return challenges after a particular date
  scope :on_or_after, ->(date) { where(arel_table[:date_started].gteq(date)) }

  # return all but these challenges
  scope :excluding, ->(id) { where.not(id: id) }

  def previous_user_challenge_date_started
    user.challenges             # get the users challenges
     .excluding(self)           # but not this one
     .on_or_after(date_started) # that are on or after the start date
     .order('date_started ASC')
     .last
  end

end
```

Also here is the obligatory link to an awesome article about using scopes: [Mastering ActiveRecord and AREL](http://danshultz.github.io/talks/mastering_activerecord_arel/)

Comment: Scopes really are great, *especially* when you describe them in ways that are easily chained.

Comment: Very good. Thank you! I ran into a related problem beyond the scope of the question if you'd be willing to indulge - so now let's say there are 3 challenges with the same `date_started`. If a user clicks `next` it will just iterate back and forth between challenge A & challenge B, and not challenge C. Any ideas how to fix this? If you'd prefer I'll create new question.

Comment: I would tackle the issue more like pagination over `user.challenges`. However, you're only showing 1 item per page. You could use `offset` and `limit` to do this. Or, you could work out the index of `self` in `user.challenges.load`. Previous would be `user.challenges[index - 1]`and next world be +1. Hope that gives you singing to work with

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you compare id of the clicked challenge.

Add another where condition for the id not equal to clicked challenge.

so, add  **.where('id != ?', clicked_id)**